# Правильность оформления условия в if

Tags: c++, логика

Всем привет, если в конструкции с условием это самое условие очень большое и не помещается на экране в одной строке, будет ли правильным это условие разбить на несколько строк? Пример будет ниже

```
if (view->isChecked(this->x() + 100, this->y() + 100) &&
        view->getFigureTeamByCoords(this->x() + 100, this->y() + 100) == "BLACK" &&
        !view->isChecked(this->x() + 200, this->y() + 200)) {
        return true;
    } else if (view->isChecked(this->x() - 100, this->y() + 100) &&
               view->getFigureTeamByCoords(this->x() - 100, this->y() + 100) == "BLACK" &&
               !view->isChecked(this->x() - 200, this->y() + 200)) {
        return true;
    } else if (view->isChecked(this->x() + 100, this->y() + 100) &&
               view->getFigureTeamByCoords(this->x() + 100, this->y() + 100) == "BLACK" &&
               !view->isChecked(this->x() + 200, this->y() + 200)) {
        return true;
    } else if (view->isChecked(this->x() - 100, this->y() + 100) &&
               view->getFigureTeamByCoords(this->x() - 100, this->y() + 100) == "BLACK" &&
               !view->isChecked(this->x() - 200, this->y() + 200)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

сразу извиняюсь если что-то говорю не так

Comment: Мне не кажется, что у вас третье условие совпадает с первым?... А четвертое со вторым?

Comment: я это уже исправил, суть вопроса в другом

Comment: Не знаю, в вопросе-то не исправили...

Comment: что-то вы делаете не так, если у вас такие огромные условия. Вы сами в них путаетесь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если все же надо третье +100/-100, а четвертое -100/-100, то можно:

```
for(int i = -1; i < 2; i+=2) for(int j = -1; j < 2; j+=2)
{
    if (!view->isChecked(this->x() + 100*i, this->y() + 100*j)) continue;
    if (view->isChecked(this->x() + 200*i, this->y() + 200*j)) continue;
    if (view->getFigureTeamByCoords(this->x() + 100*i, this->y() + 100*j) == "BLACK")
        return true;
}
return false;
```

Всяко короче...

Comment: круто, не знал что так можно, но вопрос все таки еще остался, если условие большое, можно ли на несколько строк его разбить? Работать то будет, но будет ли правильным такое написание?

Comment: Делайте так, чтоб было 1. правильно и 2. понятно для читающего человека. Если работать будет - значит, уже правильное, осталось так, чтоб было понятнее...